# How can I make one GitHub Pages website be a subdirectory of another GitHub Pages website?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a page at `x.github.io` which links via `www.x.org` (through CNAME and DNS changes).

I have another entirely different standalone site which I want to be accessed when someone goes to `x.github.io/newsite/` (or `www.x.org/newsite`). I have put the repository of the new site under the organization `github.com/x/newsite/` as that is where I have `github.com/x/x.github.io/` as I was told by GitHub staff but I'm not sure how to connect the two.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use any Apex domain (**x.org**) once across all GitHub repositories. Allowing otherwise could cause some serious conflicts and other issues.

To achieve what you're talking about, you'll need to include the new site in a `/newsite` directory of the **x/x.github.io** repository.

If you aren't too fussy about making it exactly **x.org/newsite**, you might be interested in making it **newsite.x.org** subdomain instead. Find out how-to [here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-subdomain/).